# How to get first selected related products in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart, related-products

I'm working with Magento 2, I have one product in cart and I want to show related products for cart products. I get current product using the quote to get all items.  Once I have fetched current product's ID and object. Now, I want show related products using current product. Below is my code.

```
$relatedProducts = $currentProduct->getRelatedProducts();
```

I am able to get related products using above code, but related product showing by created product ID using my above code. I want show related products based on selection of related product. I want show first two selected related products from related 10 products. 
Is there any way to get first selected related products *not by ID*

Comment: could you explain this , " But I want show related products based on selection of related product. I want show first two selected related products from related 10 products." ? as per my understanding you want related products of currently added item's related product ?

Comment: Currently i got related products listing but related products listing is based on created date. But I want related products listing that means ordering based on first selected related products . I have three product name for product  is product1, product2,product3  three product content ids 2,4,6. And I have selected product3, then product2 and then product1.  After selected this ordering I got results  product1, product2, product3  the result is come based on created date orderby Ids. But I want result based on first selection related products that  results will be  product3, product2,prod